# Controls on top of a tab have the incorrect background in Win32 GUI

Tags: windows, winapi, win32gui

I'm trying to create a Win32 application (with no other dependencies for GUI) that has a set of tabs and controls within those tabs.  I have created the following reasonably minimal example following [Raymond Chen's guidelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20211110-00/?p=105889), which seem to contradict [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/create-a-tab-control-in-the-main-window), but either way it doesn't seem to affect drawing:

```c
#include <Windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#include <uxtheme.h>

#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

LRESULT CALLBACK wndproc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_DESTROY: {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_PAINT: {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            // All painting occurs here, between BeginPaint and EndPaint.

            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW));

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            return 0;
        }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    HINSTANCE hinst = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;
    icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    icex.dwICC = ICC_TAB_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

    LOGFONT lf;
    GetObject (GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT), sizeof(LOGFONT), &lf); 
    HFONT hfont = CreateFont (lf.lfHeight, lf.lfWidth, 
        lf.lfEscapement, lf.lfOrientation, lf.lfWeight, 
        lf.lfItalic, lf.lfUnderline, lf.lfStrikeOut, lf.lfCharSet, 
        lf.lfOutPrecision, lf.lfClipPrecision, lf.lfQuality, 
        lf.lfPitchAndFamily, lf.lfFaceName); 

    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[]  = L"Window Class";

    WNDCLASS wc = { 0,
        wndproc,
        0,
        0,
        hinst,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        (LPCSTR)CLASS_NAME
    };

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    HWND window_hwnd = CreateWindow((LPCSTR)CLASS_NAME, "Tabs Example", WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 640, 480, NULL, NULL, hinst, NULL);
    SendMessage(window_hwnd, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfont, TRUE);

    HWND tab_hwnd = CreateWindow(WC_TABCONTROL, "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 640, 480, window_hwnd, NULL, hinst, NULL);
    SendMessage(tab_hwnd, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfont, TRUE);

    TCITEM item;
    item.mask = TCIF_TEXT | TCIF_IMAGE;
    item.iImage = -1;
    
    item.pszText = "One!";
    TabCtrl_InsertItem(tab_hwnd, 0, &item);

    item.pszText = "Two!";
    TabCtrl_InsertItem(tab_hwnd, 1, &item);

    item.pszText = "Three!";
    TabCtrl_InsertItem(tab_hwnd, 2, &item);

    HWND groupbox_hwnd = CreateWindow(WC_BUTTON, "Groupbox", WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_GROUPBOX, 10, 32, 600, 400, window_hwnd, NULL, hinst, NULL);
    SendMessage(groupbox_hwnd, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfont, TRUE);

    HWND text_hwnd = CreateWindow(WC_STATIC, "Static Text", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_CENTER, 100, 100, 100, 100, window_hwnd, NULL, hinst, NULL);
    SendMessage(text_hwnd, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfont, TRUE);

    ShowWindow(window_hwnd, SW_NORMAL);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

}
```

The problem is that, when it is run, it draws the tab content incorrectly. Each control in the tab has a background with the window background color:

(note the incorrect background behind the "Groupbox" text and "Static Text")

[image]

I have tried using a transparent background using `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` like so:

```c
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC: {
    HDC hEdit = (HDC)wParam;
    SetBkMode(hEdit, TRANSPARENT);
    SetTextColor(hEdit, RGB(0, 0, 0));
    return GetStockObject(HOLLOW_BRUSH);
}
```

But that results in incorrect rendering of the groupbox:

(note the groupbox divider being drawn behind the "Groupbox" text)

[image]

Also, I have tried reordering the tab control to the bottom, which makes the Groupbox display incorrectly:

```
SetWindowPos(tab_hwnd, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
```

(note the grey background under the whole groupbox)

[image]

Comment: Put your controls on a child dialog, and use `EnableThemeDialogTexture` to make its background blend in with the tab.

Comment: "groupbox divider being drawn behind the "Groupbox" text" seems like 100% expected result when making the text transparent...  Implementation detail is that the divider is always drawn as a closed rectangle, but the text normally covers part of it, making it look like it is drawn with a gap.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Is that the only way around it?  I've been trying to avoid creating a child dialog to be able to programmatically create the full GUI, but i can only find info about creating dialogs through resource files.

Comment: @BenVoigt You're right, I've just seen it around as a workaround for other controls and I wanted to demonstrate that I knew about it and it didn't work for my use case.

Comment: @pmx: Since you have a solid color, you could just set the background color of tab children (`IsChild(tab_hwnd , lParam)`) to the tab color.  (Instead of `SetBkMode` call `SetBkColor`)

Comment: also `return GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);`

Comment: that was my backup plan.  I forget if 3DFACE actually matches Windows 10/11 tabs, though.  either way the actual color is an eyedropper away

Comment: Just as long as you don't want to run it on XP or on any theme where the tab background is a gradient :)

Comment: Handle WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC with the correct background color brush. Using the transparent approach will cause artifacts, when your window is redrawn, because the background isn't redrawn.

Comment: Why aren't your tab control contents created as children of the tab control?  Ahh, that's the point of Raymond's blog post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most controls `WM_PRINTCLIENT` will do.

```
case WM_PRINTCLIENT:
    {
        // Paint area outside tabs control here if needed.
        ...
        // Now paint tabs area
        RECT    r1, r2;
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, &r1);
        GetWindowRect(tags_hwnd, &r2);
        POINT   old;
        SetWindowOrgEx((HDC)wparam, r1.left - r2.left, r1.top - r2.top, &old);
        LRESULT result = SendMessage(tabs_hwnd, WM_PRINTCLIENT, wparam, lparam);
        SetWindowOrgEx((HDC)wparam, old.x, old.y, 0);
        return result;
    }
```

`WM_PRINTCLIENT` should paint whole client area, so there is a reason that child dialog or helper window are often used for this.

Unfortunately STATIC control doesn't call `WM_PRINTWINDOW`, `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` can be used instead.

We can delegate some work to tabs control, but it will not work correctly for gradient or bitmap backround..

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    return SendMessage(tabs_hwnd, WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC, wparam, lparam);
```

**Edit:**
Removed simplified (and controversial) implementation for gradient and or bitmapped background.

Full version needs following steps:

1. Create compatible DC.
2. Create bitmap.
3. Select bitmap into dc.
4. Adjust origin.
5. Render with `WM_PRINTCLIENT`.
6. Create brush from bitmap.
7. Cleanup and return brush.

**Screenshot:**

This program doesn't use dialog templates. Controls are created by code and automaticly layed out by geometry manager in resizable window.

Usung XP because it has tabs with gradient background.

[image]

**EDIT: Full Approach In Context:**

For the program presented in the question, the WndProc function can be replaced with the following (note the global variables, as well) to show correct output (I did not have an XP environment to fully confirm correct rendering with gradients, but it seems fine on 11):

```
HWND tab_hwnd;
HBRUSH hBrush = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK wndproc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_DESTROY: {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_PAINT: {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            // All painting occurs here, between BeginPaint and EndPaint.

            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW));

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            return 0;
        }
        case WM_CTLCOLOR:
        case WM_CTLCOLORBTN:
        case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC: {
            // create a brush that copies the tab's body
            // NOTE: this brush would have to be recreated when the window is resized, this is just an example
            if (!hBrush) {
                RECT rc;

                GetWindowRect(tab_hwnd, &rc);
                HDC hdc = GetDC(tab_hwnd);
                HDC hdc_new = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);  // create a new device context to draw our tab into
                HBITMAP hbmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top); // create a new bitmap to draw the tab into
                HBITMAP hbmp_old = (HBITMAP)(SelectObject(hdc_new, hbmp));  // replace the device context's bitmap with our new bitmap

                SendMessage(tab_hwnd, WM_PRINTCLIENT, hdc_new, (LPARAM)(PRF_ERASEBKGND | PRF_CLIENT | PRF_NONCLIENT));  // draw the tab into our bitmap
                hBrush = CreatePatternBrush(hbmp);  // create a brush from the bitmap
                SelectObject(hdc_new, hbmp_old);    // replace the bitmap in the device context

                DeleteObject(hbmp);
                DeleteDC(hdc_new);
                ReleaseDC(tab_hwnd, hdc);
            }

            // use our previously created brush as a background for the control
            RECT rc2;

            HDC hEdit = (HDC)wParam;
            SetBkMode(hEdit, TRANSPARENT);

            GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rc2);  // get control's position
            MapWindowPoints(NULL, tab_hwnd, (LPPOINT)(&rc2), 2);    // convert coordinates into tab's space
            SetBrushOrgEx(hEdit, rc2.left, rc2.top, NULL);  // set brush origin to our control's position

            return hBrush;
        }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

[image: Example application with groupbox and static text drawing correctly]

Comment: Actually, forwarding `WM_CTLCOLOR*` to the tab control is the only necessary step.  You most certainly do NOT do painting in those events, and you CANNOT pass `wparam` and `lparam` of WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC to WM_PRINTCLIENT.

Comment: Second part is needed for gradient or bitmap background. Unfortunately this code is taken from larger application that is using multitude of C++ classes. Converting it fo raw winapi would be rather though task. And yes there is error in `SendMessage` call.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this solution working (I assume it was ripped out of your application, so it's totally understandable that adapting it to my code would be difficult), but I really appreciate the help here.  I found another resource with your "full" approach and it got it all working for me.  I'll write it up in context of my example now.

Answer (score 0):

Group boxes are implemented as do-nothing *buttons* rather than static controls.  So, in addition to handling `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` to fix the background color of the static text, you should also handle [`WM_CTLCOLORBUTTON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-ctlcolorbtn) to fix the group box.